# Node voltage method with dependent current source

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image: Circuit]
[image: solution]

Can anyone help me to solve this circuit using node voltage method? Because in the solution, I don't understand why there is just 3I1 only.

Comment: 3I1 is not a solution, it is one of the parameters

Comment: Where's I1 in your circuit?

Comment: Jin, I'm not sure what your question is. The solution is just what you wrote at the bottom. And it looks like you were starting out using KCL, which is the `node method`. So I'm not quite understanding what you feel you need to hear. Or is that a copy of notes you took, but don't follow?

Answer (score 1):

Look, I think I completely agree with your process. But before I go there, let's take a look at the schematic again:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGmAlr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think you can see why I've set up the currents this way. In order for the currents at \$V_x\$ to sum to zero, the above must be true. The value of \$R_3\$ really doesn't matter much. All it does is change the voltage across \$I_1\$. But otherwise it has no impact on that branch.

Getting back to the KCL (nodal):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_x}{R_1}+\frac{V_x}{R_2}+3\cdot I_1&= \frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}
\\\\
\frac{V_x-V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}+\frac{V_x}{R_2}+3\cdot I_1&= 0\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

And that's pretty much what you wrote, already. So I don't find any problems with your work product.

Since \$I_1=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}-V_x}{R_1}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_x-V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}+\frac{V_x}{R_2}+3\cdot \frac{V_{_\text{IN}}-V_x}{R_1}&= 0\:\text{A}
\\\\
\frac{V_x}{R_1}+\frac{V_x}{R_2}+3\cdot \frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}&= \frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R_1}+3\cdot \frac{V_x}{R_1}
\\\\
V_{_\text{IN}}&=\left(1-\frac12\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)V_x
\end{align*}$$

From that, and given your resistor values, it's clear that \$V_x=2\cdot V_{_\text{IN}}\$.

So what's your difficulty here? I think you did just fine.